# Constraints similar to Generics or AttributeUsage for non-generic interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, constraints

**EDIT:** This is more of a good design question that came up while refactoring and combining reusable code into a library.

I am consolidating frequently used code from over the years to a library and interfaces play a large part here. While refactoring, one of the main categories that interfaces are split in include whether they were designed for mutable or immutable scenarios. Consider the following:

**Mutable and Immutable:**

```
interface ICloneable<T> { T Clone (); }
```

**Immutable:**

```
interface ISomeInterface { T SomeFunc (); }
```

**Mutable**

```
interface IInitializable { void Initialize (); }
interface ICopyable<T>: IInitializable { T CopyFrom (T source); T CopyTo (T destination); }
```

The case of `IInitializable` is the odd one out as there is no reason for it to accept a generic parameter. However, without one, it cannot enforce usage with classes only.

I assume that constraints do not exist for non-generic types so the question is whether there is a way to enforce this at runtime (or better at compile time)? Besides generics, attributes can also be restricted (not that it matters here).

Of course I could just make the interface generic but that wouldn't be a good enough reason would it? Any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the reason why you want to prevent a value type from implementing `IInitializable` in a structural way? I mean, that is really something that comes up in a code review or code analysis. Besides, it isn't already forbidden by the language, so there are some scenarios where it makes sense. In any case, if the object has an Initialize() method, then its consumer should not know or care whether it is a struct, class, or an instant Martian, right?

Comment: @KeithPayne: Your last sentence is certainly true. My question is more from a library developer's point of view. If I want to show clear intent that `IInitializable` is meant for reference types, I could for example structure the namespaces appropriately in addition to documentation of course. The reason I asked on S.O. was to see if there was any mechanism available to enforce the behavior rather than merely suggest it. Short of alternatives, I am considering eliminating such interfaces entirely while porting the function signatures to other interfaces that already have generic constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in the C# language to prevent a `struct` from implementing your interface.  Any type is free to implement any interface so long as it can satisfy the methods described there.

However you can constrain the usages of `IInitializable` to only work with implementations that are `class` types.  For example

```
void M<T>(T value) where T : IInitializable, class
```

This can be used to constrain your usage scenarios to `class` only and hence get the guarantee you are looking for

Comment: Thanks. Does your example intend to make the `void Initialize ()` method of the interface generic? If so, I would be inclined to drop the interface altogether and shift the method to whichever other interfaces require it.

Comment: @RaheelKhan no, it just leaves the interface exactly as is

Comment: In that case I am not sure I understand. Since my library does not have any implementations of these interfaces, where does the method `M<T>(T value)` go?

Comment: @RaheelKhan that's a question you need to answer.  Why do you have the interface if you don't ever use it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Java.

C# supports operator overloading and user-defined conversions, so your `ICopyable<T>` seems redundant.

Also, unless you really need a generic `Clone()` method, you're probably just as well-off defining copy constructors; you can always use double-dispatch internally. By 'really need', I mean, is the algorithm *truly* generic?

**Edit:** `Clonable` in Java was a kludge to get around the fact that it didn't support templates/generics. C# does, so your algorithm can match on type and you can use simple-to-use copy construtors.

Finally, WRT to `Initialize()`, if it's a generic no-argument method, why not just put the code in the constructor? It's going to be far easier for people to use and understand. If your object is only partially inialised at contruction, then you need to check and throw `InvalidOperationException`s anyway, so why complicate your interface?

If the `Initialise()` method is to support polymorphism, then it shouldn't be in an interface, as it's an implementation detail - interfaces are about how people *use* your objects, no how you build them; the fact that that the compiler does some checks on them is secondary to their purpose.